How to validate an SSL certificate based on the root-certificates present in the local machine's certificate store?
I run my program in standard user privilege and I assume the API ValidateServerCertificate uses the root-certificates from the local user certificate store to validate the SSL certificate.
Code sample from the C#.
// The following method is invoked by the RemoteCertificateValidationDelegate.
public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
      object sender,
      X509Certificate certificate,
      X509Chain chain,
      SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
   if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
        return true;

    Console.WriteLine("Certificate error: {0}", sslPolicyErrors);

    // Do not allow this client to communicate with unauthenticated servers.
    return false;
}

Requirement: I need the SSL certificate validation based upon the root certificates present in the local machine certificate store.
I came up with a logic to to compare the thumbprint of the provided Root - SSL certificate with the ones present in the local machine certificate store.
X509Store store = new X509Store("Root", StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

X509ChainElement rootElement = chain.ChainElements[chain.ChainElements.Count - 1]; //To get the root of the chain
X509Certificate2 rootCert = rootElement.Certificate;

foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in store.Certificates)
{
    // Compare the thumbprint of each certificate
    if (cert.Thumbprint.Equals(rootCert.GetCertHashString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // Certificate found
        return true;
    }
}
return false;

But is there a better way to perform this ? I am using .NET-FW Version 4.

What are you trying to achive with this? If you want to check the chain in more detail you may just look at the chainstatus if the root is untrusted or missing(PartialChain). If the status is ok the root certificate must have been found.

I want to use only the root certificate present in the local machine store for the certificate for the validation. I guess by default the SSL certificate validation is done by verifying the root certificate present in the local user certificate store.

Pls get into mmc - Add-Remove Snap-In - Certificates - Current User. Then click on Certificates - Current User top folder and choose View - Options - Show Physical Stores - Checkbox enabled. Now expand Trusted Root Certification Authorities, you will see where do certificates come from. As seen on the screen user's Trusted Root Store includes  Local Computer  - Trusted Root Certification Authority Store. So no need for reading computer trusted store. It is actually in the user's Trusted Root Certification Authority folder.

You can try some other way:
Export your certificate (Private key) in .pfx format (with password) and keep it in some folder location.
To export your certificate, you can also use DigiCert Utility, which can be downloaded from the below link:
var cert_Path = "D:\YourFolderLocation\YourCertificate.pfx";
var cert = new X509Certificate2(cert_Path, "Certificate_Password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

Now, try your code with this.
